# How to obtain all solutions for cos(x)*cosh(x) == 1 in Sympy?

Tags: sympy

Following is the best I can get.

```
map(lambda n: nsolve(cos(x)*cosh(x)-1,x,3.14/2+3.14*n),range(9))

[mpf('0.0039941152964418809'),
 mpf('4.730040744862704'),
 mpf('7.8532046240958376'),
 mpf('10.995607838001671'),
 mpf('14.137165491257464'),
 mpf('17.278759657399481'),
 mpf('20.420352245626061'),
 mpf('23.561944902040455'),
 mpf('26.703537555508186')]
```

If you change range(9) to range(10), sympy will return an error.

```
ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (1.59798e-17 > 2.1684e-1
9)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments.
```

I have asked this in the Mathematica site, Mathematica seems can provide the solutions quite accurate and fast. Check this out: [how-to-obtain-all-solutions-for-cosx-coshx-1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67594/how-to-obtain-all-solutions-for-cosx-coshx-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice example of using an intelligent initial guess. If you just provide a tolerance you can find the additional solution:

```
>>> len([nsolve(cos(x)*cosh(x)-1,x,3.14/2+3.14*n,tol=1e-12) for n in range(10)])
10
```

Note, however, that the function is very steep in the region of the roots and it is unlikely that you will every end up with an x value that will make the function value small. If you know that your initial guesses leads to a root and not a discontinuity, you can safely use the verify=False to skip the verification of the solution (and verify it yourself, perhaps by taking the slope into account). I always feel safer using the `bisect` method, however, in these cases:

```
>>> f
cos(x)*cosh(x) - 1
>>> bounds = lambda i: (3.14*i, 3.14*(i+1))
>>> root = lambda i: nsolve(f, bounds(i), solver='bisect', verify=False)

>>> root(0)
mpf('0.0')
>>> root(99)
mpf('312.58846903218443')
>>> root(100)
mpf('315.73006168577422')
```

You can see that the function at this point is very large, but if we normalize by the derivative of the function the answer looks better:

```
>>> ans = _
>>> f.subs(x, ans).n(2)
2.3e+122
>>> (f/f.diff(x)).subs(x, ans).n(2)
-3.4e-15
```

Note: currently, it will not work to pass a normalized function to nsolve so it can be used in the solving process: nsolve only works with the numerator of the function you pass.